# sql query for joining 3 tables

Tags: sql-server-2008

table A: userid
         name

table B: accid
         userid
         accno

table c: loanid
         userid
         amt

Hi frnds,
I want to take name of customer from table A, accno from table B and they doesn't include in table c.
help me

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you show what you have tried?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT a.name, b.accno
FROM a inner join b on b.userid = a.userid
where a.userid not in (select distinct userid from c)
```

what about this Query this will work fine i think

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT a.name, b.accno
FROM tableA a 
JOIN tableB b on a.userid = b.userid
LEFT JOIN tableC c on a.userid = c.userid
WHERE c.userid IS NULL
```

Doing a left join and checking that the values returned are null, checks that there isn't a record in table c for records in tables a and b.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

```
;with cte as
(Select a.name,b.accno,a.userid
from tableA a
join tableB b
on a.userid = b.userid)

select x.name,x.accno
from cte x 
where x.userid not in (select userid from tableC)
```

**Solution 2:**

```
;with cte as
(Select a.name,b.accno,a.userid
from tableA a join tableB b 
on a.userid = b.userid)
select x.name,x.accno
from cte x 
where x.userid in(select c.userid 
                 from cte c 
                 except 
                 select tc.userid 
                from tableC tc)
```

**Solution 3**

```
;with cte as
(Select a.name,b.accno,a.userid
from tableA a join tableB b 
on a.userid = b.userid)

select x.name,x.accno
from cte x
left join tableC tc
on x.userid = tc.userid
where tc.userid is null
```